# How to indicate param is optional using inline JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

According to the JSDoc wiki for [@param](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam) you can indicate a @param is optional using

```
/**
    @param {String} [name]
*/
function getPerson(name) {
}
```

and you can indicate a param [inline](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/InlineDocs) using

```
function getPerson(/**String*/ name) {
}
```

And I can combine them like the following, which works ok.

```
/**
    @param [name]
*/
function getPerson(/**String*/name) {
}
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to do it all inline if possible.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I found a way to do this using Google Closure Compiler [type expressions](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#param-type-varname-description). You put an equals sign after the type like so:
`function test(/**String=*/arg) {}`

Comment: WebStorm /IntellIDEA supports this notation

Comment: @PeterAronZentai, I'll add WebStorm/IntelliIDEA supports it as a result of me putting a feature request in for it :). They now support the majority of the Google Closure Compiler type expressions which is great.

Comment: Not working for me for an optional second parameter.

Answer (score 218):

From [official documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html):

## Optional parameter

> An optional parameter named foo.

```js
@param {number} [foo]
// or:
@param {number=} foo
```

> An optional parameter foo with default value 1.

```js
@param {number} [foo=1]
```

Comment: I was asking how to do it inline. The example you are providing seem to be the same as what I showed in my question.

Answer (score 78):

After some digging up I found these are ok as well

```
/**
 * @param {MyClass|undefined}
 * @param {MyClass=}
 * @param {String} [accessLevel="author"] The user accessLevel is optional.
 * @param {String} [accessLevel] The user accessLevel is optional.
 */
```

Just slightly more visually appealing than `function test(/**String=*/arg) {}`

Comment: Those are valid (and documented in JSDoc help), but they are not **inline** - which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Question is about inline JSDoc notation. This is interesting information, but does not answer the question

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using inline type comments on function arguments and are wondering how to mark a function argument as optional in that notation, I found that just assigning default values to the optional arguments worked. If you want the default to be `undefined` you have to set it explicitly as well though, otherwise the argument won't be marked as optional (even if it preceded by already optional arguments):

```js
function demo(
  /** @type {String} */ mandatory,
  /** @type {Number} */ optional1 = 0,
  /** @type {Number} */ optional2 = undefined
)
```

If you hover over `demo` in your IDE you should see both `optional1` and `optional2` showing up as optional now. In VSCode that is indicated by `?` after the argument name (TypeScript notation). If you remove `= undefined` from `optional2` you will see only `optional1` being optional which is of course nonsense so the default value here must be explicit like I alluded to in the above paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The most complete answer will be from the [official typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#param-and-returns).

```
// Parameters may be declared in a variety of syntactic forms
/**
 * @param {string}  p1 - A string param.
 * @param {string=} p2 - An optional param (Google Closure syntax)
 * @param {string} [p3] - Another optional param (JSDoc syntax).
 * @param {string} [p4="test"] - An optional param with a default value
 * @returns {string} This is the result
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

With TypeScript's handling of JSDoc, this is not possible: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47653

While you can mark a param as `@type { ... | undefined }`, its optionality does not change, because **all** parameters are optional.

> The way you mark optionality/non-optionality is by whether you put the param name in brackets, but there's no param name in this syntax, so only modifying the type (rather than also modifying the optionality in a way you can't control) is the most intuitive thing to do.

So with TS, you'll *have* to go with external `@param` comment blocks.