# How do I represent an optional object parameter with default values in JSDocs?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a simple function that needs to be documented using JSDocs that has an optional nameless object parameter with default values. This is what I am talking about:

```
function (param1, { attr1 = 0, attr2 = 'something', attr3 = {} } = {}) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Here is what my current JSDoc look like, but it doesn't seem to be right.

```
/**
 * @param {string} param1
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {number} [options.attr1=0]
 * @param {string} [options.attr2='']
 * @param {Object} [options.attr3={}]
 */
```

How do I appropriately use JSDocs for this particular case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to indicate param is optional using inline JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873927/how-to-indicate-param-is-optional-using-inline-jsdoc)

Comment: Next to the duplicate, you probably would describe the type for your second parameter

Comment: I don't believe this is a dupe, as it's not asking for the JSDoc to be inline.

Comment: I actually did look at the thread that is being claimed is a dup and indeed none of the answers address my question from what I can tell. Not only is it not inline I want, but it doesn't address the particular case of using the optional object param with various properties

Comment: I'm using VSCode and have a similar JSDoc. It seems to be showing up correctly. What exactly 'doesn't seem right'?

Comment: It wasn't being shown correctly, basically was just giving me the `any` type. If this is the case, perhaps there was an issue with refreshing in time. Will give this a second check