# Google Apps Script: how to create autocomplete with optional param using JSDOC?

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete, jsdoc

Using jsdoc, I'd like to have optional parameter (like when you start typing `=split(` and it shows the last 2 params are optional. Google's [custom function page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete) shows an example of jsdoc applied to a custom function but doesn't show optional params. It does point you to [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html), and if you browse there you will find that it lists two ways of showing optional parameters:

```
* @param {string} [somebody] - Somebody's name.
* @param {string=} somebody - Somebody's name.
```

with the second one being even a `Google Closure Compiler syntax`. But None of these worked.

I've check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383589/jsdoc-for-showing-optional-arguments-in-google-sheets-autocomplete-dropdown) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873927/how-to-indicate-param-is-optional-using-inline-jsdoc), and the first link is basically my question, but the answer just says "Google doesn't support it", which I find to be a very non-compelling answer as I have not seem anywhere Google stating they don't support it. So, my question is, did anyone make it work or has answers to it?

Comment: That is in fact my point. I'm following the bug report. Thanks.